# using Context API in React Native(expo)

Tags: react-native

refactoring my React Native code, I planned to use context API not redux. because it has just props drilling. and I made api file, cleared my app.js code and expo start. it had error.
I checked 3-4 times if there has bad logic, but I think there aren't.
please check if there has wrong one.

this is my context API file

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const AptInfoContextStore = createContext();

const AptInfoContext = (props) => {
  const [recentLocation, setRecentLocation] = useState();
  const [filteredDistrict, setFilteredDistrict] = useState();
  const [isLocationActive, setIsLocationActive] = useState(true);
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [searchTextValue, setSearchTextValue] = useState();
  const [apartmentData, setApartmentData] = useState();
  const [aptLocData, setAptLocData] = useState();
  const [pressedAptData, setPressedAptData] = useState();
  const [isAptPressed, setIsAptPressed] = useState(false);
  const [pressedAptLocData, setPressedAptLocData] = useState([]);
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);
  const [weatherLocData, setWeatherLocData] = useState({});

  const AptInfoStore = {
    recentLocation,
    setRecentLocation,
    filteredDistrict,
    setFilteredDistrict,
    isLocationActive,
    setIsLocationActive,
    dataLoaded,
    setDataLoaded,
    searchTextValue,
    setSearchTextValue,
    apartmentData,
    setApartmentData,
    aptLocData,
    setAptLocData,
    pressedAptData,
    setPressedAptData,
    isAptPressed,
    setIsAptPressed,
    pressedAptLocData,
    setPressedAptLocData,
    weatherData,
    setWeatherData,
    weatherLocData,
    setWeatherLocData
  };

  return (
    <AptInfoContextStore.Provider value={AptInfoStore}>
      {props.children}
    </AptInfoContextStore.Provider>
  );
};

export default AptInfoContext;
```

and this one is App.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard,
} from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

import addressData from "./API/realEstate/addressData.json";
import getFilteredGeoLocation from "./API/realEstate/getFilteredGeoLoc";
import getAptTradeAPI from "./API/realEstate/getAptTrade";
/* API */

import Detail from "./components/Detail";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import { AptInfoContextStore } from "./context";
/* components&screens */

import useFonts from "./hooks/useFonts";
import geoLocationControler from "./API/weather/grid";
import AptInfoContext from "./context";
/* custom-hooks */

export default function App() {
  let pressedLocValue;
  const AptInfosCtx = useContext(AptInfoContextStore);

  const [isFont, setIsFont] = useState(false);

  **// I console.log AptInfosCtx, and result was undefined //**

  AptInfosCtx.searchTextValue ? (
    (pressedLocValue = AptInfosCtx.searchTextValue?.법정동코드
      .toString()
      .substr(0, 5))
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
  const aptObj = { setState: AptInfosCtx.setPressedAptLocData };
  const weatherObj = { setState: AptInfosCtx.setWeatherLocData };

  const getLocationHandler = async () => {
    const { granted } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (!granted) {
      AptInfosCtx.setIsLocationActive(false);
    }
    const {
      coords: { latitude, longitude },
    } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ accuracy: 5 });
    if ((latitude, longitude)) {
      geoLocationControler("toXY", latitude, longitude, weatherObj);
    }
    const location = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(
      { latitude, longitude },
      { useGoogleMaps: false }
    );
    AptInfosCtx.setRecentLocation(location);
  };

  const findCityNumberHandler = () => {
    if (AptInfosCtx.recentLocation) {
      addressData.forEach((v) => {
        if (
          v.시도명 == AptInfosCtx.recentLocation[0].city &&
          v.읍면동명 == AptInfosCtx.recentLocation[0].district
        ) {
          return (
            AptInfosCtx.setAptLocData(v.법정동코드.toString().substring(0, 5)),
            AptInfosCtx.setFilteredDistrict(v.시군구명)
          );
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  };
  const DismissKeyboard = ({ children }) => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
      {children}
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );

  const today = new Date();
  let year = today.getFullYear();
  let month = ("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  let day = ("0" + new Date().getDate()).slice(-2);
  var aptdate = year + month;
  let date = `${year}${month}${day}`;

  let hours = today.getHours();
  if (parseInt(hours) < 10) {
    hours = `0${hours}00`;
  } else hours = `${hours}00`;

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsFont(true);
    getAptTradeAPI(AptInfosCtx, pressedLocValue);
    getWeatherDataAPI(AptInfoContext);
    getLocationHandler();
    findCityNumberHandler();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeatherDataAPI(AptInfoContext);
  }, [AptInfosCtx.recentLocation, AptInfosCtx.weatherLocData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    findCityNumberHandler();
    getAptTradeAPI(AptInfosCtx, pressedLocValue);
  }, [AptInfosCtx.recentLocation, AptInfosCtx.aptLocData, pressedLocValue]);

  console.log(AptInfoContext.test);

  if (!dataLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={useFonts}
        onFinish={() => setDataLoaded(true)}
        onError={(error) => console.warn(error)}
      />
    );
  }

  let screen = <Home />;

  if (isAptPressed) {
    screen = <Detail />;
    getFilteredGeoLocation(AptInfosCtx.pressedAptData, aptObj);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <DismissKeyboard>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.rootContainer}>
          <AptInfoContext>{dataLoaded ? screen : dataLoaded}</AptInfoContext>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </DismissKeyboard>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rootContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "black",
    height: 1000,
  },
});
```

I tried asking GPT(3.5) and re-read my codes but I can't find and understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your context will be undefined unless it's in a component inside your consumer component tree.

For example, the app could look like something like this.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <DismissKeyboard>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.rootContainer}>
          <AptInfoContext>
            <WeatherDataApp />
          <AptInfoContext/>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </DismissKeyboard>
    </>
  );

}
```

and a separate component called `WeatherDataApp` should have all the business logic related to consuming the API. This component should have access to the context, as it's inside the AptInfoContext container.

I personally think that making these separations are a good practice, as you can separate the top level configuration level settings, and distribute the separation of logic across subcomponents.

Comment: so thanks! it worked! I think I've learned a lot :))